# Cannot convert string to DateTime in uwp

Tags: c#, wpf, winrt-xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

```
private string GetSystem()
{
    StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();

    DateTimeFormatter[] basicFormatters = new[]
    {
        // Default date formatters
        new DateTimeFormatter("shortdate"),

        // Default time formatters
        new DateTimeFormatter("longtime"),
    };

    DateTime dateandTime = DateTime.Now;

    foreach (DateTimeFormatter formatter in basicFormatters)
    {
        // Format and display date/time.
        results.Append(formatter.Format(dateandTime));
        results.Append(" ");
    }           
    return results.ToString();
}

dateString = GetSystem();
format = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
provider = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
try
{           
    result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Debug.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
}
```

I'm getting the error

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

while running this code can anyone suggest some idea to resolve my problem.

Comment: What did the dateString look like when the error occured? maybe you are trying to parse the 30th of february or the 2nd of month 15.

Comment: What is your `dateString` _exactly_? Debug your code and tell us. Also be aware, you are not using `provider` _anywhere_ in your code.

Comment: His datestring is (you can see it in `GetSystem`) a concatenation of a `shorttime` string, a space, and a `longtime` string. Obviously `ParseExact` can't translate that with a format string of `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Note that `dd-MM-yyyy` is a fairly odd format - `yyyy-MM-dd` is much more common.

Comment: Off topic: Please remove irrelevant tags. This has nothing to do with WPF, UWP-Xaml, winrt-xaml and if we are pushing it, even uwp!

Comment: This is the output of dateString = "‎30‎-‎05‎-‎2016 ‎14‎:‎54‎:‎18 " . I also tried by Trim the string so, that empty space got removed still getting the same error

Comment: the dateString you provide looks fine until converted into ASCII or HEX. This is what 30 should look like in ASCII: `034 051` and this is your string: `034 226 128 142 051 048 226 128`. The Problem is either in the DateTimeFormatter or in the StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

In UWP apps, while using **Format Template** like `shortdate` or `longtime`, by default it will use user's default global context which are shown in **Settings** under **Time & Language**. And in my computer, they are set as following:
[image]
So when I use your `GetSystem` method in my side, the `dateString` is like

```
6‎/‎1‎/‎2016 ‎1:‎44‎:‎43‎ ‎PM
```

and obviously this can't be parsed with `format = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";`. So I think using a fixed custom date and time format string here is not a good practice.

Then even when the format of your `dateString` matches the `format` you've used in `DateTime.ParseExact` method, you will also get the error: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`.

This is because, when we use `DateTimeFormatter.Format` method, there are some **invisible 8206 characters** in its return value. So your `dateString` looks like `30‎-‎05‎-‎2016 ‎14‎:‎54‎:‎18`, but actually it's not `30-05-2016 14:54:18`. To see this clearly, we can convert the `dateString` to char array. Here using "shortdate" template for example:

```
var dateString = new DateTimeFormatter("shortdate").Format(DateTime.Now);
var array = dateString.ToCharArray();
foreach (var item in arry)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item);
}
```

And the char array will like:
[image]

So to solve your problem, I'd suggest you use [The General Date Long Time ("G") Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6).

> The "G" standard format specifier represents a combination of the short date ("d") and long time ("T") patterns, separated by a space.

You can use this format specifier like following:

```
var dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
```

And then convert string to DateTime like:

```
var result = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
```

Or

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "G", null);
```

the `provider` here is `null` which represents the `CultureInfo` object that corresponds to the current culture is used. If we use wrong culture here, we will also get `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime` exception.

If you do want to use `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` format, you can use some code like:

```
var dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

And the convert is as same as above, only in this scenario the `provider` parameter is not important.